# Understanding inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to understand some basics in django inheritance - I'm sure it is something trivial, buy I just can't get it.

I've got my CartItemForm(forms.ModelForm) and I override **init** method to get user from post.request, like that:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And it works, but I don't really get why it doesn't work when I inherit init method first:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
```

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

What am I missing here?

Comment: because `forms.ModelForm` doesn't recognize keyword `request` but in the first case you remove it by `pop`

Comment: Because then `kwargs` will still contain `request`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the [base class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L280) uses an explicit list of keyword args, and `request` isn't one of them

```
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                 renderer=None):
```

For completeness, it works before hand because you're `pop`-ing the request keyword out of the keyword dictionary and no longer exists when you're calling super